# FreeBSD turning off offloading

Tags: freebsd, ifconfig

How can I turn off the following in FreeBSD?

- tx checksum offloading
- rx checksum offloading
- tcp segment offloading
- large segment offloading

Comment: This is an old thread https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/disabling-nic-features-with-ifconfig.339/ One user suggested `ifconfig nfe0 -txcsum -rxcsum`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a BSD system, so it's all documented in the ifconfig manual page (https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ifconfig).  Basically, it's "ifconfig em0 -rxcsum -txcsum -tso -lro" to disable, and the same thing without dashes ("-") to enable.  Substitute "em0" with your interface name; do "ifconfig" without arguments to show available interfaces.